# Angular directive attributes cause an error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying write an angular directive to make a substring of an attribute that is passed in. Below is my code:

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
     <div><substring message="This is a test."></substring></div>
     <div><substring message="So is this." ></substring></div>
</body>
```

Angular/Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

});

app.directive('substring', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    scope: { text: '=message' }, 
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        //alert(attrs.message); 
        var str = attrs.message;

        scope.text = str.substring(1, 4);
    },
    template: '<H1>{{text}}</H1>'
};
});
```

When I try running this I get the following error:

> HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
>   File: directive.html
>   Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'is' is an unexpected token at column 6 of the expression [This is a test.] starting at [is a test.].

Also, I have tried changing

```
'=message' to '@message'
```

but that just causes the substring stuff I am doing in the link function to get ignored.

Why the error? Is Angular not seeing that stuff in the quotation marks as a string and instead trying to parse out some command? Most importantly, how do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Please put the error. Or if it's possible reproduce the error on jsfiddle or any other similar tool

Comment: @jcvegan - I have been trying to post the error, but Stackoverflow blocks my question saying that the error is improperly formatted code. Do you know away around this?

Comment: Have you tried putting your message in single quotes? `message="'So is this.'"`

Comment: @Dave You're accessing text with`attrs.message`. Why do you need to define new scope?

Comment: @cem I am not sure what you mean. This is my first time writing a directive (and still new to Angular). The examples I followed were doing this. I tried removing the custom scope, and I ran into a problem with the directive only using the last value in both spots. Can you elaborate one what you mean?

Comment: Hey Dave, did the accepted answer solve your problem? Curious before I dive into it.

Comment: @TSmith Yes it did. Thanks.

Comment: Great. If you go with this solution, you can remove the part in the link function where you are getting the message via the attrs collection and just use the directive scope that's already setup:
scope.message.substring(1,4)

Comment: @TSmith Is that because I am using the '@' symbol in scope {message: '@' }?

Comment: @Dave: Yep. If you didn't want to create a property on the scope, you could simply have an empty scope object --> scope: {}  and then use the attrs collection in the link() function. Either way, like you observed, you need an isolated scope for the directive so the last message doesn't overwrite the first one. So to recap:
scope : {}  with the attrs collection usage
scope: {message:'@'} with no attrs collection usage

Comment: @TSmith I tried your suggestion and got an error saying "message is undefined."  Nevermind, I just tried again. It is working. I must have made a mistake the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `@` for text binding and the rest of your code works perfectly.

Working example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

});

app.directive('substring', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      message: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      //alert(attrs.message); 
      var str = attrs.message;
      scope.text = str.substring(1, 4);
    },
    template: '<H1>{{text}}</H1>'
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div>
    <substring message="This is a test."></substring>
  </div>
  <div>
    <substring message="So is this."></substring>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Could you explain the difference between '@' and '=' when it comes to using them in directives? I am still confused about when I should use one or the other.